# Conditions for socialism?

Tags: government, socialism, fascism

Historically, fascism and extreme right wing movements have become popular in response to certain conditions.  These conditions include:

- real or perceived economic instability at the national level
- xenophobic / extreme nationalist rhetoric in response to real or perceived external threats
- The fear of technological or industrial advancements
- A large group of people feeling socially/politically disenfranchised
- etc.

I tend to view fascism as entirely negative, but for the purpose of this post, I'd like to keep it as close to neutral as possible.  Given that the above stated are fairly accurate pre-conditions for a fascist government to come to power or at least gain traction, what pre-conditions would have to exist in a country for socialism to arise?  I am not talking about totalitarianism wearing communist clothing; but, rather, an actual socialist or communist government.  What would have to be happening nationally for a communist government to become a legitimate political possibility?

Comment: Welcome to the Politics SE. Politic-fiction is unfortunately off topic here.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy - can you explain how this qualifies as that?  I realize this is speculative, but it seems like a legitimate political theory question.

Comment: "Given that the above stated are fairly accurate pre-conditions" needs a credible citation, and "what pre-conditions would have to exist in a country for socialism to arise" is politic-fiction - you cannot argue it with reliable sources. Plus, socialism would need to be defined properly, because to date it has only ever arisen as totalitarianism wearing communist clothing.

Comment: " I am not talking about totalitarianism wearing communist clothing" - to make this anything but a Worldbuilding.SE material, you first need to prove that the communist state is possible in actual Earth reality on any OTHER conditions, since history clearly shows that ***every single one*** socialist/communist state of any meaningful size that was tried so far either devolves into totalitarian state faster than you can say Quidditch, or doesn't last long enough.

Comment: Additionally, most socialist/communist states were nationalistic and extremely xenophobic and for non-Asian ones, largely antisemitic, so I guess horseshoe theory wins.

Comment: For an actual long run socialist government, you can look at swedish history, they were run by socialists during more than 70 years. For governments of a few terms, you can look at either Europe  (most countries have had one) or south america  (5 years ago, all countries but colombia were run by socialists).

Comment: Those are two very different questions, a communist government requires a revolution by definition, a socialist one does not

Comment: @user4012 Another example is Yugoslavia which is the only country which successfully resisted Soviet influence. There were purges in the 1950s against pro-Soviet citizens, but after the 1960s it stabilized and it was the only one of the countries in Eastern Europe which granted citizens the freedom to travel (Which is kind of problematic for totalitarian states, isn't it?). This was also necessary because the economy was always problematic so a huge size of the population worked in the West. It existed for 47 years.

Comment: @user5751924 - social democrats != socialists. It's usually right wingers who are accused of not understanding the difference :)  And Latin America is exactly what I meant. The socialist governents either don't persist, OR, you have Cuba and Venezuela.

Comment: @user4012 Socialist is the ancient term that used to encompass a lot, even communists. But except in special cases, like Venezuela (non-democratic socialists) or Nepal (democratic communists), when both forces are present, the socialist party is socio-democrat, and the communist party is for a single party. Besides, democracy was the main reason for the scission between communists and socialists.

Comment: The only condition I can see for the emergence of a socialist current in a society is that such society is capitalist. As to succeeding in implementing their program, then it is way more complicated - anyway, more complicated than what can be reasonably packed into a comment.